# Storing and serving different sized images

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

I have a website where the user will upload their profile picture. The picture will then be separated out to 3 images. 1 as the original image, 2 as a medium sized thumbnail, and 3 as a small sized thumbnail. What is the best way to store a process like this in a database? I was thinking something like this:

Image table

```
id  user_id  size  img
1   2        S     /img/s/avatars/ex.jpg
2   2        M     /img/m/avatars/ex.jpg
3   2        L     /img/l/avatars/ex.jpg
```

We take the original image and split them off like this. Does this look like a good idea, or is there a better way to something like this. I am using Django as my backend.